# swap elements by comparing data attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple div elements with `data-timestamp` attribute

What I want to do is sort these `div`s by `data-timestamp` (newer to older). 
I decided to loop through elements and swap their positions.  If an element's next sibling has a newer `data-timestamp` than the current element, then next sibling inserts before current.

```js
$.each($('.sorted-chat-item'), function( i, value ) {
        //current element's timestamp
        var date = new Date($(value).attr('data-timestamp'));
        //all elements
        var list = $('.sorted-chat-item');

        for(var j = i+1; j < list.length; j++){
            //next element's timestamp
            var nextDate = new Date($(list[j]).attr('data-timestamp'));
            if(date < nextDate){
                $(list[j]).insertBefore( $(list[i]) );
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sorted-chat-item' data-timestamp="2017-09-01 18:09:22">2017-09-01 18:09:22</div>
<div class='sorted-chat-item' data-timestamp="2017-09-01 18:01:27">2017-09-01 18:01:27</div>
<div class='sorted-chat-item' data-timestamp="2017-09-01 18:31:36">2017-09-01 18:31:36</div>
```

but it doesn't sort correctly. Any idea, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing is called bubblesort and it needs more iterations to sort the whole list. You must repeat the each function as long as there are changes

Comment: You're missing a `"` in the last div to close the `data-timestamp` attribute.

Comment: thanks for reply, can you please be more specific?

Comment: I've edited your question, your code seems to work to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Sort Array of DOM Objects based off DOM values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346196/jquery-sort-array-of-dom-objects-based-off-dom-values)

Comment: Easiest method will be to put all the DOM elements in an array, use a pre-built sort mechanism then put them back.   See linked duplicate, changing the answer's `$().find('.header h3').text()` to `$().data("timestamp")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this, and you should probably use the id of the parent rather then `parent()`, but i imagine something like this would work

```
function sortByCustomDate(a, b){
    var aDate = new Date($(a).attr('data-timestamp'));
    var bDate = new Date($(b).attr('data-timestamp'));
    return ((aDate < bDate) ? -1 : ((aDate > bDate) ? 1 : 0));
}


var $parent = $('.sorted-chat-item').parent();
var $allElements = $('.sorted-chat-item');
$allElements.sort(sortByCustomDate);
$parent.empty().append($allElements);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is in plain js, but it does what you want. We're first sorting the items, then removing and appending them to their container

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('sorted-chat-item')).sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(b.getAttribute('data-timestamp')).getTime() - new Date(a.getAttribute('data-timestamp')).getTime();
}).forEach(e => {
  let p = e.parentNode;
  p.removeChild(e);
  p.appendChild(e);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='sorted-chat-item' data-timestamp="2017-09-01 18:09:22">2017-09-01 18:09:22</div>
  <div class='sorted-chat-item' data-timestamp="2017-09-01 18:01:27">2017-09-01 18:01:27</div>
  <div class='sorted-chat-item' data-timestamp="2017-09-01 18:31:36">2017-09-01 18:31:36</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your plain JS approach but OP was already using jQuery. I assume you were writing yours as I was writing mine, but the idea is the same ;) So have a +1

Comment: @DarkMukke thanks, yours is a good one two. You got my revenge.. :D